# Help identifying his really weird plant bought as a husk cherry

Tags: identification

I purchased a 4-pack of husk cherry seedlings from a local farm. Three of the 4 grew normally and are starting to produce the husks. But the 4th plant is very strange. It has prickly looking berries. It must be some other type of plant. Any ideas what this is?

[image]

Comment: I fear that are galls and not berries, but I cannot tell you which plant it is